# javascript convert array of objects to string to store in s3

Tags: javascript, mongodb, amazon-s3

My data returned from Mongo looks like this:

```
[ { _id: 5510dcfb7ffb9ec87db017ca,
deviceId: '150622',
link: 'http://egauge15062.egaug.es/cgi-bin/egauge-show?S&s=0&n=6&C&Z=LST-8',
timestamp: 1427168502,
ct1: 3411,
ct2: 532,
ct3: 7,
ct4: 43,
ct5: 642 }, etc.........]
```

I am trying to archive the data into s3 and I need to convert that into string. I tried using .join and .tostring on the array and it ends up looking like this when I push it to the server.

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]]
```

Any ideas how I can fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Where obj is the javascript object you want to store.

This will return a serialised string which can then be re-used easily in javascript when you require it next, which looks exactly like what Mongo is returning you.